# dynamically populated table add additional row on parameter

Tags: jquery, html

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
  $("#searchresult").append(tr)
}
var tablerow = $("#searchresult tbody").find('tr').length;
if (tablerow < 10) {
  console.log(tablerow);
  for (var i = 0; tablerow > 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1" id="searchresult">
  <thead>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

I want to add additional row on this dynamically created table so that i can have ten row in total. I am stuck on part where if the dynamically added rows is less than 10 how should this be done.

any idea is appreciated!

`UPDATE`

`I add data to the table dynamically. In the instance that the table row in tbody is less than 10 i want to add more row (blank) to make it total of 10 rows`

Comment: Not clear.. Can you explain bit more..

Comment: I add data to the table dynamically. In the instance that the table row in tbody is less than 10 i want to add more row (blank) to make it total of 10 rows @GuruprasadRao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking for the available `rows` length iterate your `for loop` from the the **number of rows** already present in `table`.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var tr = $('<tr/>');
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
  $("#searchresult").append(tr)
}
var tablerow = $("#searchresult tbody").find('tr').length;
if (tablerow < 10) {
  //start iterating from number of rows created i.e. tablerow and here it is 4
  for (var i = tablerow;i<10 ; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>');
    //if you want blank rows here remove 'i'
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td id=''>" + i + "</td>");
    $("#searchresult").append(tr)
    //again repeat the same step.. You can also think of keeping this in a function
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1" id="searchresult">
  <thead>
    <tr align="center">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
</table>
```

Comment: `for (var i = tablerow;i<10 ; i++) {` totally missed this one. i feel so down thank you for the great answer appreciate it

Comment: Anytime... Happy coding.. :)